# React - Function Parameter Inversion (Index Confusion)

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs, codepen

While playing a little bit with React.js, I found it interesting that if you use a function which has the index parameter but as the second instead of the first one, the returned element gets confused.

```
View Example
```

http://codepen.io/AlexandruDoda/pen/VPKeOa

As you can see in the Pen, the output shows {element} as if it was the index element. Just a curiosity, anybody aware why this happens behind the scenes?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The unexpected behoaviour is caused by the logic, you're not doing it right. [Facebook documentation provides](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html) good and bad practises.  Let's say you have an arary `const lists = ['first', 'second', 'third']`. To append it correcty you would shoud do soemthing like this:

```
{ lists.map(element, index) => <li key={index}>{element}</key> }
```

If you wanna dig deaper, the documentation provides a lot more informations ;)

Comment: It totally makes sense when mapping an array, but in my Codepen I am simply looping and repeating the same render 10 times.